# Whats the point of ActiveRecord associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am still new to rails and something I still don't understand is why people use associations in ActiveRecord.

For example if I have a class Patient and a class Doctor I would give the Patient a column called "Doctor ID" and then if I wanted to find how many Patients a Doctor had I would count the patients where Doctor is equal to their Doctor ID. Similarly if I wanted to find the name of a Doctor assigned to a patient, I would just find the Doctor where the Patients Doctor ID is equal to the Doctors ID.

I can do all of this explicitly and simply without the use of associations.

From my point of view ActiveRecord associations just complicate this, what is the benefit of using it rather than manually using my own ID system?

Comment: Are you asking about associations in rails or what is the point of a relational database? Associations are just shortcuts for relational queries so I am a bit confused by the question the way it is posed

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you're actually describing one kind of association - a one-to-many.  Rails lets you automate this so that you don't have to write out the SQL to count the patients the doctor has.  So, instead of opening a db connection, executing the SQL, and parsing and counting the result set, you can just find the assign the doctor in question to, say, `my_dr`, and execute `my_dr.patients.count`.

You see a bigger benefit from many-to-many associations, where writing the SQL by hand involves joining with a link table.  For example, doctors have many patients, and patients may have multiple doctors.  So, in addition to a `Doctor` model and a `Patient` model, you'd need a `DoctorPatient` model to hold connections between the two.  The SQL for that is longer than you'd need in the first example, but rails still lets you use `my_dr.patients` to retrieve and iterate over a doctor's patients.

So, the benefit is in avoiding writing the SQL yourself.  I can use SQL, but I find it to be temperamental and clumsy compared to actual programming language syntax, so being able to short-circuit the database commands is a real time and energy saver.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that you don't have to write pure SQL. If ActiveRecord didn't exist, you would have to write the same redundant queries (redundant in the sense that the only thing that changes is the table/column names) to retrieve associations across many different tables. Rails does this for you through AR associations.

Comment: Don't forget `dependent: :destroy` and friends. Or extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, without associations, you can get the count of how many patients a Doctor object (named `doctor`) has using:

```
Patient.where(doctor_id: doctor.id).count
```

But I wouldn't say that using associations complicates things, rather it simplifies things, by writing:

```
doctor.patients.count
```

If you are new to associations, and you already understand databases, then it might seem like an additional complication to learn a new thing.  However, if you use it, after a while you will find that it streamlines things.

With the exception of has-many-through, there really is no huge gain, but there is a lot of little simplifications in the code which add up over time.

Comment: I don't know I'd say `joins` and `includes` both offer huge gains of their own. Such as `Doctor.joins(patients:{records: :medications}).where(medications: {name: 'xyz'}).distinct` to find `Doctors` prescribing a specific `Medication`. This is obviously far simpler than using id based datasets

Comment: @engineersmnky Good point.  If you use associations, you can refer to them in `joins` and `includes`.